# Haskell's Lambda case doesn't work in Prelude as expected, parse error

Tags: parsing, haskell, lambda

I've got the definition of function below ( a new sum function )

```
Prelude> :set +m
Prelude> :set -XLambdaCase
Prelude> let sum2=\case
Prelude|     []->0
Prelude|     x:xs->x+sumw xs
Prelude| 

<interactive>:31:5:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
```

Why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems.

1. Since `let` is a block herald, the next token after `let` (in this case, that is `sum2`) sets the indentation level for a block. Since you put the `[]` and `x:xs` patterns at the same indentation level as `sum2`, they are therefore part of the `let` block -- when you probably intended them to be part of the `\case` block. The simple solution is to indent the two patterns by at least one more character.
2. Because you are allergic to spaces, you are accidentally trying to define an operator named `(=\)`. Add a space to make it clear that you are trying to define `sum2` instead.

Together, you get:

```
Prelude> let sum2= \case
Prelude|      []->0
Prelude|      x:xs->x+sumw xs
Prelude|
Prelude>
```

Comment: Still fails with: <interactive>:28:12: parse error on input `case'

Comment: @viksantata Check that you indeed enabled the `LambdaCase` extension, as you did in your question.

Comment: Ah, still indentation problem: I need extra space to make my [] after sum2. Thanks very much.